# Rails+Apache app won't serve static asset in prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

It works in development, but in production I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/zoom.png"):
```

The guides says Apache should serve static data if you do `rake assets:precompile` (I do). I set `config.serve_static_files = true` to cheat around this, but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas for what to do or how to debug this?

Rails: 4.2.4 · Ruby: 2.3.1

Comment: Are you using any of the helpers? `image_tag`, `image_url`, `asset_url`?

Comment: That clue solved it!

I was using `url('zoom.png')` and changing to `image-url('zoom.png')` made it work.

Thanx!!

Answer (score 0):

I was using `url('zoom.png')` in my SASS.

Changing to `image-url('zoom.png')` made this work.

*Thanks to @Leito!*